# Is there a tool to check if two meshes will fit together?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing, measurement

I need to make a car from several parts. I created the lower body and the upper body. These parts (separated objects) will be 3D printed. I want to check if the objects fit together. I need a tool which will show the edges (or faces) which are intersecting, and I need a glue gap too.

I can't find this tool.
Thanks.

***car parts*** 
[image]

***glue area***
[image]

Comment: duplicate on of them , add Boolean modifier with intersection  and see if it result in a new object, also if you can post an image of the two parts highlighting the glue area  so we get a idea how complex it is

Comment: Ok I attached the images. [1](http://hgplsoft.com/gabika/ask/i1.jpg), [2](http://hgplsoft.com/gabika/ask/i2.jpg), [3](http://hgplsoft.com/gabika/ask/i3.jpg), [4](http://hgplsoft.com/gabika/ask/i4.jpg) I marked the glue with red color. This is a toy.

Comment: Thanks your answer. The boolean solution is a very slow, circumstantial and the boolean modifier can crash the blender.

Comment: Just on a side note, make sure the normals of your wheel hubs are calculated correctly, they appear to be facing inwards. Go into edit mode, select all vertices, and press `Ctrl`+`N`

Comment: @user13438 it seems that what you need is in [blender 3D printing toolBox](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox) it has intersection test ,mesh clean up.....check it and report back

Comment: Note that blender has some of those tools integrated now, see the wiki: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Mesh_Analysis